# How to open a vue component with URL (vue - router)?

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-router

I have an application which works with Laravel 5 + VueJs and vue-router menu

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu" >
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><router-link to="/authors/">Authors</router-link></li>
        <li><router-link to="/donate/">Donate</router-link></li>
        <li><router-link to="/feedback/">Feedback</router-link></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><router-link to="/userfiles/">Files</router-link></li>
        @if (!Auth::check())
            <li><a href="/home">reg</a></li>
        @else
            <li><a href="/home/">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/logout/">logout</a></li>
        @endif
    </ul>
</div>
```

but if I try directly open URL ( for example sitename/authors/) I got an 404 error. What should I do to open my vue-component?

Comment: Are you using history mode with vue-router? Read the caveat [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html#caveat)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but here is what I think is happening:

Your server is not configured to handle an SPA. If you want to use Vue as an SPA with multiple pages you need to configure your server to reroute all request to the index.html file. This is pretty easy if you are just using a regulair webserver, just search for (nginx, apache, etc.) SPA configuration.

Comment: thanks, but i am using Laravel and all requests to the public/index.php